# R - split sample of n into 5 groups of size x

Tags: r, split, permutation, percentage

Say I have a sample of 100 and I want to divide that sample into 5 groups of unequal sizes. But, I want all possible permutations of sizes for each group where each group must be made up of the following sample sizes- 5%, 10%, 20%, 50%. So for example one permutation could be  50%, 10%, 10%, 10%, 20%  another could be 5%, 5%, 50%, 20%, 20%.   Is there r code that can help me figure out all the possible permutation of group sizes?

```
data=runif(100)*100
vec= rbind(c(10,10,10,20,50),c(5,5,50,20,20))
datasplit=split(sample(data), rep(1:5, vec[1,]))
```

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example.  Perhaps you need `combn/cut/quantile` combination

Comment: @akrun  I added an example as much as I could. I'm trying to create "vec" above with all possible combinations as described above.

Comment: In your code, the `split` is on equal lengths.  I thought you want to have the data split by `vec[1,]`, `vec[2,]` and also the sum of the combinations should be equal to 100?

Comment: You're right. Sorry there was a bug which is now fix to vec[1,]. The sum of combinations meaning: 5%,+ 5% + 50%+ 20%+ 20% =100.

Comment: randomly order the sample, then take the first 5 as group1, 10 group2, etc; then repeat with different sizes, no need to complicate it

Comment: I posted a solution below.  Please check if that works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create the `combinations/permutations` of the `vector` ('v1') using the functions from `gtools`) to get a `matrix` output.  Then, remove the rows where the `sum` of the elements is not equal to 100 (`rowSums(m1)==100`).  Loop through the rows of the matrix (`apply` with `MARGIN = 1`) and `split` the `sample` of 'data' into 5 groups based on the values in the rows of 'm1'

```
library(gtools)
#m1 <- combinations(4, 5, v1, repeats.allowed = TRUE)
m1 <- permutations(4, 5, v1, repeats.allowed = TRUE)
m2 <- m1[rowSums(m1)==100,]
r1 <- apply(m2, 1, FUN = function(x) split(sample(data), rep(1:5, x)))
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c(5, 10, 20, 50)
set.seed(43)
data <- runif(100)*100
```

Comment: You're awesome. Thank you, akrun!!